# Echo response of curl

Tags: php, loops, curl, while-loop

Is it possible to echo the response of the curl inside a while loop, every after the curl process is done and not after the loops are done.

example

```
$chk1=0;
while (strpos($g1, '<label for="username" class="sr-only">')) {
$g = curl_init();
curl_setopt($g, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "".$d."/COOKIE/".$ii['cookie']."");
curl_setopt($g, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "".$d."/COOKIE/".$ii['cookie']."");
curl_setopt($g, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://xxxx.net/login/index.php');
curl_setopt($g, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($g, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($g, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($g, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($g, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($g, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $rndua);
$g1 = curl_exec($g);

$chk1++;
if ($chk1 == 20) {
break;
}

}
echo "https://xxxx.net/login/index.php $chk1 requests sent";
```

I am doing a while loop to repeat a curl process into my website for example 20 times and I want that in every 1 loop it does it will echo "https://xxxx.net/login/index.php 1 request sent" and in the next loop add new line https://xxxx.net/login/index.php 1 request sent.

Answer (score 0):

sure. move your echo line 2 lines up, so it's inside the while's `{}`